# Regular expression to match a word starts and ends with a combination of special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which gives me words which starts with `<!=` and ends with  `=>`. For example if there is a sentence what is your `<!=name=>`, the result should give me `name` because it matches my pattern.

I have read to use this `^` for starts with and `$` for ends with, but I am not able to match a combination of special characters.

Comment: usually you can use `\b` for word boundaries. So you should use `\bXY\w+` where XY is your character combination

Comment: then you should use `<!=\b(\w+)=>` or you can even remove the `\b` since the special characters are not part of the word-charcter class. Have a look at: https://regex101.com/r/qDrobh/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment. You can use `<!=(\w+)=>` because the exclamation mark and equal sign are not part of word-character class you can simply test for those characters and match the word characters between them. check:https://regex101.com/r/qDrobh/4

For multiple words you can use:`<!=((?:\w+| )*)=>`
See:https://regex101.com/r/qDrobh/5

Comment: Your solution is working fine for single word.what if i have to match more than one word inside that special character.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm.